# Managed object context not merging changes from background context

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a dual managed object context setup where I have a parent/child MOC relationship. The parent is responsible for writing directly to the database on private queue (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) and then I have a child context that is responsible for pulling and saving data for the main thread (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType).

The contexts work as they should as in when I make changes to the main queue context and save it, then the changes are merged to the background queue context and written to the database on a background thread.

The issue I am having is when I write data directly to the background queue context and then try to merge it to the main queue context. The objects are stored correctly in the store, and when I merge the changes it seems to work. However, if I attempt to make a NSFetchRequest against the main queue context directly after saving the data to the store, then the data is stale and not the correct updated data.

Below are the code excerpts that should help give you all an idea of what I am doing. Some things to note is the logic that returns the NSManagedObjects from the JSON work correctly. Also, I have tested and the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification runs before the UI attempts to make any fetch requests against the main queue MOC. Do you all have any ideas what is going on?

```
// Context Setup
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext
{
    if (_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext != nil)
        return _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
        _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
        _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;
    }
    return _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil)
        return _managedObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _managedObjectContext.parentContext = _backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext;
        _managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
        _managedObjectContext.stalenessInterval = 0.0;
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// save MOC
- (void)saveManagedObjectContext
{
    @try
    {
        // perform synchronous process to save to the main MOC
        [_managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^(void)
        {
            __block NSError *error = nil;

            // push any changes in the main context to the background writer context
            if (![_managedObjectContext tryLock])
                [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManger - Unable To Lock Managed Object Context: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

            if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error])
                [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManger - Error Saving Managed Object Context: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

            [_managedObjectContext unlock];

            // save the background writer context
            [_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext performBlock:^(void)
            {
                error = nil;

                if (![_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext tryLock])
                    [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManger - Unable To Lock Background Writer Managed Object Context: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

                if (![_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext save:&error])
                    [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManger - Error Saving Background Writer Managed Object Context: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

                [_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext unlock];
            }];
        }];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        [VS_Log VS_LogException:exception];
    }
}

// This code runs when attempting to save objects from a web service call
[_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext performBlock:^(void)
    {
        // create a new process object and add it to the dictionary
        __block VS_CoreDataRequest *request = [[VS_CoreDataRequest alloc] init];

        // .. LOGIC HERE DESERIALIZES THE JSON AND RETURNS AN ARRAY OF NSMANAGEDOBJECTS

         // perform synchronous process to save to the main MOC
         @try
         {
             NSError *error = nil;

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext];

             if (![_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext tryLock])
                 [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManger - Unable To Lock Background Writer Managed Object Context: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

             if (![_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext save:&error])
                 [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManger - Error Saving Background Writer Managed Object Context: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

             [_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext unlock];

             // submit changes back to the forground context
             [_managedObjectContext performBlock:^(void)
             {
                 NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                 // iterate through the updated objects and find them in the main thread MOC
                 for (VS_BaseManagedObject *object in request.objects)
                 {
                     // get the object from the main managed object context
                     NSError *error;
                     NSManagedObject *obj = [_managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:object.objectID error:&error];

                     if (error)
                         [VS_Log VS_LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VS_CoreDataManager - Error: %@", error.localizedDescription]];

                     if (obj)
                     {
                         [_managedObjectContext refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:YES];
                         [objects addObject:obj];
                     }
                 }

                 // RETURN FROM METHOD SO UI CAN REGAIN CONTROL
             }];
         }
         @catch (NSException *exception)
         {
            [VS_Log VS_LogException:exception];
            return;
         }
     }];

// Merges changes from parent to child context
- (void)mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_backgroundWriterManagedObjectContext];

    // merge the changes
    [_managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: Something's not making sense in the information you have provided as your code and concept look ok. Are you using a FRC to feed data to a view? If so I suspect it has more to do with your FRC. I'm not certain whether a stand alone fetch will update the MOC as you require. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling process pending changes.